# Definition of smooth surface meaning

Tags: differential-geometry

I am studying differential geometry.

Definition of surface is
S subset of $R^3$ is surface if for every $p \in S$,
exist open set U in $R^2$, open neighborhood V of p in S, differentiable map
\begin{equation}
X:U \rightarrow R^3
\end{equation}
s.t.

1. X(U) = V
2. X is homeomorphism
3. for every q in U, $(dX)_q:R^2 \rightarrow R^3$ is injective

i can understand fist and second condition for X, but third one is confusing.
As far as i know, single cone $S={(u,v,(u^2+v^2)^0.5)}$ is not surface because of the third condition of X.
but as
\begin{equation}
(dX)_q =
\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\ 
    0 & 1 \\
    \frac{u}{(u^2+v^2)^{0.5}} & \frac{v}{(u^2+v^2)^{0.5}}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
is consisted of two linearly independent vectors, it seems satisfying third condition.
My understanding of third condition is existence of tangent plane of surface but it seems to satisfy third condition but doesn't have tangent plane at O.
What was wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your $X$

$$ X (u, v) = (u, v, \sqrt{u^2+ v^2})$$

is not differentiable at $(u, v) = (0,0)$, so it cannot be a parametrization.

The single cone
$$\{ (x, y, z) : x^2 + y^2 = z^2, z \ge 0\}$$

is not a regular surface (as defined in Do-Carmo). The reason is that locally a regular surface can always be written as a graph of one of the form:

$$ z = h(x, y), \ \ y = g(z, x), \ \ x = \ell (y, z).$$

(See Proposition 3 in section 2.2 of the book) However, in the case of the single cone, it is clear that the second and the third case are not possible, while if it is the first case, then we must have
$$ h(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2+y^2},$$
but this is not differentiable at $(0,0)$. Hence the single cone cannot be a regular surface.